# PHP Including a sub namespace from class with relative qualifiers

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I am scratching my head around this. it is not that it is not working... it is just strange.

```
OS:  debian latest
php: 5.6
```

Following should work...

```
Namespace Client\Error;
class ErrorHandler{
 /**
     * @param $errorType
     * @return FatalError|InputError|SecurityError|php
     */
    private function getHandler($errorType)
    {
        $debug = require_once __DIR__ . "/Handler/$errorType.php";
        $errorType = "Handler\\$errorType";
        return new $errorType();
    }
    public function test(){
        $this->getHandler('InputError');
    }
}
```

in folder Handler inside of it is an empty class:

```
namespace Client\Error\Handler;

class InputError
{

}
```

This code works when i use the absolute namespaces  in the instantiation ( $errorType = "Client\Error\Handler\$errorType"). BUT i WANT to use relative one. Just for da lulz. They are empty the classes in the folder Handler. 
i tried to use the namespace in use on top of class with

```
Namespace Client\Error;
use Client\Handler;
```

nope. not even with class name only or without it.. is it a feature that im not aware of when you include a class from a class or some weird typo I did.

ps: error im getting is when i try to make a new class:

> Fatal error: Class 'Handler\InputError' not found in ....

Comment: "BUT i WANT to use relative one. Just for da lulz." Hate to break this news for you, but how php works is irrelevant to what you want. Read about how namespaces work: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php Also, consider writing an autoloader or generating one with composer, you won't have to include files manually.

Comment: Yes im aware of Autoladers. this is a fallback in case some nut goes nuts and breaks the Autolader. Acording the documentation using new Handler\InputError() shold work. tht is why im scratching my head.